# Laravel 5.8 The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST

Tags: laravel, methods, put, insert-update

I want to update a form with the @method('put')

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route("admin.experiences.update", [$experience->id]) }}" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
@method('put')
@csrf
```

but a have this messageError:
`The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST`
So i have used the same methode for the other form and it's worked nice.
The routes:

```
   Route::delete('experiences/destroy', 'ExperiencesController@massDestroy')- 
   >name('experiences.massDestroy');
   Route::resource('experiences', 'ExperiencesController');
```

The controller:

```
 public function update(UpdateExperienceRequest $request, Experience $experience)
{
    $experience->update($request->all());

    return back()->with('success','Expérience modifiée avec succès!');
}


public function edit(Organigramme $organigramme, Experience $experience)
{
    //
}
```

Need a help
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `admin.experiences.update` here `admin prefix did you added?

Comment: Hello Paul, I try your suggestion but not working. Thanks

Comment: remove `admin` form this and use `route("experiences.update", $experience->id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{route("experiences.update", ['id' => $experience->id]) }}" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @method('put')
        @csrf
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks Sarwary. The problem is that I had not close a <form> </form> tag in the view.

Comment: Oh, best of luck.